# Emulate printer via inline usb port

Tags: linux, printing, printers

I need to emulate/fake a printer (any printer) that is connected through a usb port without touching the hosting computer. The connection needs to be via some kind of inline connection.
What i mean is to connect something to the hosting computer usb port and connect the printer to that device on another port (or on wifi). The computer that will send the printing should not know the difference when sending a printing job and also no software should be installed on the printing computer.

I need it in order to add text to the print jobs (whether they are in PCL/Postcript/Any other format) in various places based on the text being printed.

I've found the [Red Titan](http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/capture/print2usb.html) solution, but it's working on windows and I rather work on a Linux environment.

If there is a Linux software that can emulate a printer port and can be customized for any printer type, I could just program a Raspberry Pi/Any other device to do all the conversions and editing and send it to the printer. 
I just haven't found any software that could do that via an inline usb.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/

Comment: @Zac Hi, have you ever got to implement it or find a different solution eventually?

Comment: Not yet as the project was delayed for now.